# How to solve http 500 error in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-ec2, http-error

I am trying to open a website since yesterday but facing this problem

> This page isn’t working https://www.indgovjobs.com/ is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

I searched on the net and tried all the method I could to solve the issue but wasn't able to solve it. I tried htaccess file method (but I don't have access to the admin panel due to the same issue), increasing php memory, disable plugin by renaming the folder. I have hosted the website via aws ec2 wordpress by bitnami instance.

Comment: There has to be a log for this somewhere.  You tagged this with `amazon-ec2` - are you hosting this yourself?

Comment: Yes I am hosting this myself

Answer (score 0):

Can you ssh your ec2 instance and access check the error logs? please post them here.

if you are having difficulty using ssh, check the following documentation by bitnami to troubleshoot AWS/WordPress issues.

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/troubleshoot-wordpress-issues/

Depending on OS or apache installation your location of the error log may be different. try following command

```
sudo tail -100 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: Can you please guide how to ssh my instance?

Comment: These are many ways to connect to EC2 Instance, but i prefer PUTTY,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

if you haven't use PuTTY or PuTTYGen before, you need to learn on youtube. Also you must have some prior knowledge of linux commands.

Comment: I have made a connection through putty but now I don't know the commands :( to view error logs

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check, BTW, if you do not know Linux command, I don't recommend running a live production site on EC2 instance, if your purpose is learning or development then it's fine. For production sites, first, install a stable control panel like VestaCP or Virtualmin, which are free or buy a license of Plesk or Cpanel or hire a server admin on a contract basis.